# How to convert jest unit report to generic data report which is import to sonarqube

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sonarqube, jestjs, sonar-runner

I'm doing unit and coverage testing through jest for javascript.

Coverage lcov report is imported into SonarQube while sonar scanner. But unit report is not imported into sonarqube.

I tried with jest-sonar-reporter and tried to import the report as sonar.testExecutionReportPaths. But while scanner ,

INFO: Imported test execution data for 0 files
INFO: Test execution data ignored for 119 unknown files, including:

Help me here. Let me know if any another method with docs